# Commented out variable gives PS-Terminal Error (#$Var = error)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, comments

I have a problem with VSCode terminal that started with the latest version.
It might be a bug or just a setting that I have missed, therefore I want to ask you before I report it as a bug.

```
Version 1.19.3
Commit 7c4205b5c6e52a53b81c69d2b2dc8a627abaa0ba
Date 2018-01-25T10:36:34.867Z
Shell 1.7.9
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture x64
```

I have a file with different functions that I just for Office365 administrative tasks.

I always open the file in VSCode and run it (<kbd>F5</kbd>) and then I call the functions from another file.
But with the latest VSCode upgrade, when I run the file I get these errors in the terminal window. The errors point to lines that I have commented out (`#`).
In every function I first have commented lines with explanations to every variable that I use, like this: `#$UserName = the Name of the user`.
If I remove the `$` sign after the comment-char `#` then the error for that line disappears.

The issue is not that I dont use the proper comment-based help syntax.
It is the fact that I have commented out variables that I don't use and that raises an error when I run (<kbd>F5</kbd>) the file in VSCode.

Does anyone have an explanation to why I can't have `#$Var` in my code.

```
At C:\Users\anno\OneDrive för företag\Powershell\Script\Anslut_till_O365.ps1:44 char:3
+     #$UPN: anvnamn & epostadress
+      ~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name
character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.

At C:\Users\anno\OneDrive för företag\Powershell\Script\Anslut_till_O365.ps1:45 char:3
+     #$Firstname: FÃ¶rnamn
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name
character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.

At C:\Users\anno\OneDrive för företag\Powershell\Script\Anslut_till_O365.ps1:46 char:3
+     #$Lastname: Efternamn
+      ~~~~~~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name
character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.

At C:\Users\anno\OneDrive för företag\Powershell\Script\Anslut_till_O365.ps1:47 char:3
+     #$Title: Medlemsnr inkl filialnrâ,¬
+      ~~~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name
character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
```

Below is the the first lines in the function that the Error is complaining about.

```
Function CreateNewE1User {
    #$UPN: anvnamn & epostadress
    #$Firstname: Förnamn
    #$Lastname: Efternamn
    #$Title: Medlemsnr inkl filialnrEUR
    #$Displaynamn: Visningsnamn (Kedja Ort (Butiksnamn), Förnamn Efternamn KEDJA
    #$PWD: Tillfälligt lösenord
    #param ($UPN,$Firstname,$Lastname,$Title,$Displaynamn,$PWD,$SMTP)

    Param(
        $UPN,
        $Firstname,
        $Lastname,
        $Title,
        $Displaynamn,
        $PWD='Password01'
    )

    #skapa ny användare
    New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN -FirstName $Firstname -LastName $Lastname -Title $Title -DisplayName $Displaynamn -UsageLocation "SE" -PasswordNeverExpires $false
}
```

Comment: You may want to read up on [comment-based help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-3.0).

Comment: The file is "old" and I know that I can use comment-based help but have not had the time to edit it, since I know what the functions do.

The issue is that my comments generats an error when I run the file if I have a dollar-sign after the hashtag (#$Var)

Comment: That's due to the position of your comment block. Get rid of the angles (`<>`) and it'll work fine.

Comment: I have removed the comment block surrounding the commented lines to avoid confusion.
I still get the same error on the commented out lines starting with #$UPN:

Comment: Have you thought that this is an environment thing? Meaning something has changed/gotten corrupted on your system. I say this because, I've seen this happen and it has happened to me. Code runs fine on one system and fails on another, I have that issue as we speak. Do you have another system to try.

Comment: Thank you @postanote. I uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code and now everything works.

Comment: How do I mark this question as solved/answered? @postanote just gave a comment not an suggested answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer since it did work out for the OP.

Have you thought that this is an environment thing?

Meaning something has changed/gotten corrupted on your system.

I say this because, I've seen this happen and it has happened to me. Code runs fine on one system and fails on another,

I have that issue as we speak. Do you have another system to try.

As a follow on to your issue and my associated comment. My discovery was that the latest VSCode update updated the default Keybindings, thus causing a conflict with my custom user keybindings. Once I deleted my custom keybindings which conflicted with the new default keybindings all things returned to normal.

Moral of the story, pay attention to the VSCode updates and really read the ReadMe file. Especially if you are in the habit of customizations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is the [PowerShellEditorService](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices). This is the engine used by the PowerShell extension in VS Code and is what the PS Integrated Terminal is run on.

I cannot duplicate the errors you are getting. I am on the latest release of VS Code (1.19.3) and the PS Extension (1.5.1). If you update and still get the issue you can submit it to the GitHub repo to find out why it may be doing that on your installation. My guess is it still parses the line even if you have it commented. If you block comment that whole section it will likely cause the engine to skip trying to parse each line.

Comment: Using Block comment was allready tried without any luck, 

I have reinstalled VS Code as suggested by @postanote and now the issue is gone